# Use command line argument in bash script substituted with value from script

Tags: bash, shell

I recently started bash scripting and got stuck with a very basic usecase, searched stackoverflow/google but couldn't find a way to achieve what I am trying to do.

I have a script color.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
Apple="Red"
Orange="Orange"
Banana="Yello"
echo $$1
```

What I am trying to achieve is print the color of fruit and accept fruit from command line. The output I want is

./color.sh Apple -> Red, but what I get is some random number which I think is process Id.

Comment: What you want is called "indirect expansion"

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate, see [BashFAQ #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). And BTW, what you're getting is process id with a `1` appended to the end. (`echo $$1` => `$$` == process id, `1` == literal string).

Comment: ...and as another aside, `echo $foo` is inherently buggy for the reasons given in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo). Always quote your arguments: `echo "$foo"`, or in the present case, `echo "${!1}"`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, that a lot @CharlesDuffy